# Spring Web Application

Tags: java, spring, web

I am creating a online browser game (clicking based). I have a general question about how Java works in web applications.

For example I have a class Mining and after a user logs in (using the form in html) in I want to fetch data from database to put that class certain values. And if users session will end the values from Mining will be saved to database and object will be destroyed. Can I make a new Mining object for each user that uses my application?

```
package application.data.character;

public class Mining implements PlayerStat{

private int level, exp;

public Mining(int level, int exp) {
    super();
    this.level = level;
    this.exp = exp;
}


public void addExp(int amount) {
    exp += amount;
     ExperienceHandler h = new ExperienceHandler();

     level = h.checkForLevel(exp, level);



}




public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(int level) {
    this.level = level;
}

public int getExp() {
    return exp;
}

public void setExp(int exp) {
    this.exp = exp;
}








}
```

Comment: This is more about how HTTP works than how Java works. If your users log in and have a session, any objects you put into the session will be accessible to that user, therefore different users will have different sessions and different objects in their session.

Comment: Can you refer me to somewhere or give some understanding how do I save objects to session ?

Comment: That's a broad issue that involves a lot of reading. Luckily the Spring documentation is excellent.

Comment: Do you think this is the best way? Or should i choose some other way ?

Comment: Considering that you're just starting out, it doesn't really matter which way you choose. Just be prepared that it will take longer than you probably currently think.

Comment: Look into Spring Security. You are over-complicating something that works  seamlessly out of the box and has tons of great tutorials to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

From "For example I have a class Mining and after a user logs in (using the form in html) in I want to fetch data from database to put that class certain values. And if users session will end the values from Mining will be saved to database and object will be destroyed. Can I make a new Mining object for each user that uses my application?" 
 
I am reading that every time a user logs in you instantiate an object with values in the database. Every time the user logs out, you save the values in the object back into the database. 
Yes, you can definitely create a mining object for each user. Just call the constructor for the required fields from the database.

Comment: Thank you for answer.! But what I want to know is:
If I run my application online with tomcat. And instantiate Mining objects for all users who are currently using my web app. Does it keep the Mining objects separate from each other ?

Comment: So tomcat is instantiating your object? Why don't you just fetch the data from from the database, and instantiate the objects yourself? This, you can keep a reference to each of the object, ensuring that each mining object is distinct and separate. If this is  a problem, can you tell you how tomcat instantiation works? \

Comment: I think we think of different things, sorry for my english.
I got the answer from you. So basically when I fetch data from database, and then save that data to an object, then this object will be unique to each computer(user) that uses my application?

I am just confused because how can the object be unique.

Comment: Your english is fine. I think I understand your question now. Tomcat is an apache server, so you are asking if each client user will get a different object instance. The user will get an object with fields associated with the id he enters in the html form. So the object will be the same in that the data will be the same. The reference can--most likely will--be different based on memory availability and such.